# How do I get a Malaysian transit pass?

Tags: transit-visas, malaysia

We are a group of 15 Indians traveling from India to Thailand via Malaysia. The layover is around 14 hours. Can we get out in the city to visit Kuala Lumpur? If yes how do we get a transit pass to enter the city?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

> Nationals of the following countries are only eligible when holding a visa or a residence permit issued by Australia, China, Japan, New Zealand, South Korea, Taiwan or the United States, and are departing to or arriving from these countries. They may only arrive and depart from either the main terminal or the low cost carrier terminal (KLIA2), unless they hold a residence permit.
>
> - Bangladesh
> - India
> - Pakistan
> - Sri Lanka
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Malaysia#Transit

You need to get an eVisa if you want to visit KL. VoA won't be available on the way out, although it might be on the way back:

> Nationals of  China and  India arriving directly from Indonesia, Singapore or Thailand and hold valid visa of those countries can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 7 days (that cannot be extended) at Kuala Lumpur–International (KUL), Johor Bahru (JHB), Kota Kinabalu (BKI), Kuching (KCH) and Penang (PEN), provided they hold return flight tickets and at least USD 1000 per person. [1] The visa fee is 430 Malaysian ringit, other currency not accepted as visa fee. Boarding pass or tickets are required to prove that you have arrived from a specific country.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Malaysia#Visa_on_arrival

Comment: Thanks for the answer I found this useful.

There's something else I found 

https://www.tripadvisor.in/ShowTopic-g293951-i7006-k10356206-o700-Malaysia_eNTRI_Note_Visa_Waiver_for_Indians_experience-Malaysia.html#87110062

Might be of help. I guess